# How to make ul and li style in css just for menu

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have style for my horizontal menu like this

```
<style>
 ul  {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
   float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
```

and in my HTML I have code like this for my horizontal menu

```
<ul>
 <li ><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li ><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

My horizontal menu is working, the problem is when I have another ul and li in another part of my HTML code (not for horizontal menu) like this

```
<ul>
 <li >Parth 1</li>
 <li >part 2</li>
</ul>
```

their style follow the style for my horizontal menu, I am newbie for CSS code so any help?

Comment: You can style based on id or class. You're already using a class with `.active`, so just do it the same way for the list items.

Comment: Have a look at CSS class and id selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a `class` on your `ul` and make your style rules depend on that class instead of `ul`. Don't use inline styles.

```css
.menu  {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.menu li {
   float: left;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.menu li a.active {
  float: right;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Part 1</li>
 <li>part 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, great job taking a step and learning css! You're going to love it.

What you're going to need to learn here is add a class or id in order to select just the `ul` and `li`'s within the menu.

Maybe your code will look something like this.

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
 <li ><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li ><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this case, the horizontal styling that you mentioned would have to be referred to like...

```
ul.mainMenu (or just .mainMenu)  {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.mainMenu li {
   float: left;
}

/* And so on... */
.mainMenu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Before you go much further in css, you should definitely take some time to learn about classes and ID's and how to use them as your selectors - it'll help make CSS a lot more fun. Cheers!

Comment: Very friendly and welcoming answer. I like your style!

Answer (score 3):

Assign a class to the ul and use that as a selector in your CSS:

```
<ul class="mymenu">
 <li ><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li ><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.mymenu  {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.mymenu li {
   float: left;
}

.mymenu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mymenu li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.mymenu .active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You give the menu a class `class="myclass"` or an id `id="myid"` (class is recommended), e.g.

`<ul class="menu">`, then use `.menu {...}` and `.menu li {...}` etc. to target it. That will leave any other `<ul>`s untouched.

Note, a class can be used with multiple elements, but an id must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `class` or `id` HTML's attributes:

```
 <ul id= "itemList">
  <li class="item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="item" style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Then:

```
#itemList {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#itemList .list {
   float: left;
}

#itemList .list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Using id for CSS selectors is generally a bad idea. http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

Comment: Generally means that life leads to death.